# Напишите программу, которая составляет строку, содержащую первые буквы из каждого слова заданного предложения

Tags: python

Как исправить программу, чтобы получить строку, содержащую первые буквы из каждого слова заданного предложения.

```
s = 'Привет ривет ивет вет ет т'

words = s.split() 
result = []
for word in words:

    new_word = word[0]
    result.append(new_word)

print(' '.join(result))
```

Comment: Опубликуйте ваш пример, в котором вы пытались что-то делать.

Comment: s = 'Привет ривет ивет вет ет т'

words = s.split() 
result = []
for word in words:
    
    new_word = word[0] +word[1:0] 
    result.append(new_word)

print(' '.join(result))

Comment: а все разобралась

Comment: `''.join(x[0] for x in s.split())` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'Привет ривет ивет вет ет т'
words = s.split() 
result = []
for word in words:
    new_word = word[0] 
    result.append(new_word)

print(''.join(result))
```

Comment: Срез `[1:0]` - это пустая строка

Comment: Достаточно в цикле result.append(word[0])

Comment: спасибо, исправил х)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]